# Trying to run JUNIT tests on different JVM using Maven Surefire

Tags: maven, testing, junit, maven-3, maven-surefire-plugin

I am trying to run each of my tests on different JVMs. To achieve that I am using the following Surefire Configuration:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
        <configuration>
            <forkMode>pertest</forkMode>
            <forkCount>1</forkCount>
            <reuseForks>false</reuseForks>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

This configuration seems to be running each of the TestClasses on a different machine, but I need to get each test method running on a different JVM.

When I set the attached Configurations under Intellij I am getting each test running on a different JVM.

[image]

Isn't it equivalent to what I have defined under my Surefire plugin?

Answer (score 1):

Intellij configuration, in your screenshot, is different from `pom.xml` surefire configuration.

Following is plugin documentation from Maven for `forkMode`. According to following `maven` documentation, `forkMode` is **deprecated** and can **NOT** have `method` value.

[image]

You could also try using `parallel` parameter with value as `methods`. Following is what `parallel` means:

[image]

Please refer following links for detailed understanding around parallel test execution:

https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/fork-options-and-parallel-execution.html

http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html

Comment: I thought I could replicate that behavior just using Surefire, I cannot use parallel test execution so the only way I have been able to solve this issue was to create each test in a different class and define the new maven properties forkCount and reuseForks to avoid using a deprecated property. Using this properties a new JVM will be launched per class.